# I don't understand how the following expression works

Tags: python-3.x, string, substring

This is the part of the code I have copied to see the output,

```
def check(string,sub_str):
    if(string.find(sub_str)==-1):
        print('no')
    else:
        print('yes)

# driver code for testing the above function
              
string='geeks for geeks'
sub_str='geeks'
```

*I specifically wanted to understand how this expression works* **:**
`if(string.find(sub_str)==-1):` . Also this code is for finding substrings in a given strings can some one tell if this is the optimal way, I know it is tutorial code but I have an easier way to find the substrings. Just wanted to know if that would make passing test cases easier hence the above code. Anyways thanks y'all for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `find()` returns the index of the string you are looking for. The string in front of `find()` is the one in which you are looking for the second string.

```
SentenceThatIsCompletelySearched.find(ForThisPartHere)
```

If the string you are looking for is present it will return the index (a number on which position of the sentence the string has been found).

If the string is not inside the sentence then `find()` will return -1 (a number).

So in your case you are checking if `sub_str` is inside `string` and if it is not present (return of -1) you will print "no". If it is you will print "yes".